# AJAX Submitting Single Forms on Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 2 forms on the same page and want them to submit independently of each other using AJAX. The code I currently have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#form_tab").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
                }
            });
       });
</script>
```

When I put both form id's to form_tab they both submit when the other is. How Can I make they both submit interdependently with the same code? Thanks!

Comment: Each form has a unique `id` right? Please show the HTML.

Comment: ID's *must* be unique or else you will have problems with JavaScript.

Comment: change your selector with just `form` like : `$("form").on("submit", function(){})`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay That would ensure that both (all) forms get submitted simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's *must* be unique or else you will have problems with JavaScript. You can use

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var formID = $(this).id; // get this form's id
```

Then you can use the ID, if you need to, to handle processing for each form.

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thank You! And to everyone else who also commented :)